# Vectors and class

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Im new in C++, and Im doing some encoding task and my goal is vector in main class, each EncodedFiles object contains unknown number of bites sequences of various size.

main:

```
vector<EncodedFiles> encodedAll;
for cycle
     load content of file
     encodedAll[0].setData(sequence);
```

class of object

```
class EncodedFiles{
private:
    vector<vector<bitset<3> > > allSequences;

public:
    EncodedFiles();
    ~EncodedFiles();

    vector<vector<bitset<3> > >& getData();
    void setData(vector<bitset<3> > sequence);
};
```

SetData.

```
void EncodedFiles::setData(vector<bitset<3> > sequence){
    //I passed data (sequence) here correctly
    this->allSequences.push_back(sequence);
}
```

Problem is with push_back operation. I dont know how to initialize the 2D vector without specifying their size.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you need to initialize? Where is the problem with this code? What happens when you run it?

Comment: In setData function, program crashes, exactly at line "this->....", arguments were passed into function correctly, and Im using c++11 compiler

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the `this->` notation.  The notation is used when the method parameters have the same name as the class members.

Comment: You should pass the `vector<bitset<3> >` by reference.  Otherwise the compiler is creating a copy to use in your function (taking up extra memory).

Comment: `encodedAll[0]`... It seems you don't push anything in `encodedAll`.

Comment: Memory is not an issue, in main class, that "sequence" variable changes with each iteration and after loading process it will be deleted so i cant passed that variable by reference.

Comment: The program doesn't crash because of `setData` - it crashes because of `encodedAll[0]` - which is accessing an element of the vector that hasn't been initialized and is out of bounds (which in turn invokes *undefined behavior*). You need to create objects of `EncodedFiles` in `encodedAll` first before you can access the vector